# Java JSON data type validation

Tags: java, json, validation

I'm parsing JSON files to POJOs using [Google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). GSON throws exception if a JSON file hasn't the right format, that's great. But I need type validation too, so an error is thrown if:

- Types of the JSON field don't match the types of the POJO properties.
- There are missing properties in the JSON.
- There are properties in the JSON that cannot be found in the POJO.

So if I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
    private String aString;
    private int anInt;
    private boolean aBoolean;
    private String[] anArrayOfStrings;
}
```

A JSON like the following won't validate in any case:

```
{
    "aString": 1234, // int instead of String
    "anInt": "asd", // String instead of int
    // missing aBoolean field
    "anArrayOfStrings": [1, 2, 3, 4], // int array instead of String array
    "unexpectedValue": "asd" // A field not present in the POJO
}
```

Is there any way of doing this with GSON? Otherwise, are there other JSON parsing and mapping libraries able to do this in a simple way? I mean, not having to use another JSON that contains a schema validation, like `com.sdicons.jsontools`.

The information about which properties and the types of these properties are in the POJO itself so it looks like it would be easy that GSON would be able to validate at least the types, but it doesn't, it just guesses the value of incorrect and missing values. I would need an exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid JSON:

```
{
    aString: 1234, // int instead of String
    anInt: "asd", // String instead of int
    // missing aBoolean field
    anArrayOfStrings: [1, 2, 3, 4], // int array instead of String array
    unexpectedValue: "asd" // A field not present in the POJO
}
```

Change it to this:

```
{
    "aString": 1234,
    "anInt": "asd",
    "anArrayOfStrings": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "unexpectedValue": "asd"
}
```

Comment: Tichodroma, you might mention to the OP why it's not valid. That is, comments in JSON are not allowed.